# I don't understand the logic of express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

Tags: node.js

I use this line

```
 express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Does it pass to the client post or get request?

Because if i use

```
express.get("/",function(res,req){
res.send(dataWirhDb);
}
```

There is no data on the client. If I use post request, I get data from the server.

If I use without

```
 express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

and send to the client using get request, data is received on the client.

why does this happen?

Comment: Please use a translator to assist yourself in writing the post as your english is pretty much broken.

Comment: Sorry, i make now.

Answer (score 1):

No, `express.static` does not execute any requests. It's just a setup function that tells express that it needs to serve static files, and where to find them.

In this case the location is `path.join(__dirname, 'public')` , which means the `public` folder within your application directory.

The static files (like css, images, index.html etc.) are served automatically without the need of setting up routes for them. "Served" in this context means that the server sends the file back as a response to a GET request by the client, asking for that file.